# How can I use exotic file search parameters like in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, software-recommendation, search

Windows Explorer [allows for very specific file searching parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference) such as framerate=≥30 or width:1600.

For each of these columns, a search parameter can be set:

[image: Windows columns]

This is the beginning of the list. There are many fine search parameters such as EXIF photo data, length of music, etc.

Sorting after these columns is possible, while Ubuntu and Linux Mint file managers even invert ↓ and ↑ when sorting files. In Windows, the size column indicating ▽ means large to small In Linux, ▽ means that the larger files are down and smaller files are up, which makes less sense because the long edge of the triangle pointing down (▽) logically indicates *large first.*

#### How can I use exotic search parameters such as metadata of media files be searched for in Linux?

In my particular case, I am looking for a list of 240 fps videos.

Comment: By default - there's no way to search for such metadata. However, you can either use a command-line for that, or add a custom script to run from right click menu in Nautilus ( that's the filemanager's name, much like Explorer in Windows ).

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Is there any compareable equivalent to Windows Explorer?

Comment: Nothing, as far as I know